# Magento 2 Cross site scripting vulnerability PCI scan

Tags: magento, xss, pci-compliance, magento2.2

PCI scan in our servers recently failed due to cross-site scripting vulnerability in Magento 2 pages. They have requested like below to reproduce the issue.

```
REQUEST:
GET /2018-2019-random-url.html?<script>alert('TK00000031')</script> HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Host: example.com
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0

Evidence: <script>alert('TK00000031')</script>
```

But we couldn't reproduce it in any browsers. Only in IE it detects it's cross-site scripting and stops the execution of the page. Magento support also didn't help us and not sure how to fix it.

Does anyone faced the same issue and got the resolution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: PCI compliance and XSS tags were not available in Magento stackexchange and it might be related to programming since we needed to prevent the XSS issue on a code level.

Comment: This site isn't "might be related to programming". You need to make it programming-related. Drop in some code. Make it explicitly about programming in the question.